# Can different threads access different methods of a specific instance of a stateless EJB?

Tags: multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, ejb, stateless-session-bean

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean1 {

    pulic void method1() {
        //method implementation
    }

    pulic void method2() {
        //method implementation
    } 
}
```

Consider a specific instance of `MyBean1`. Then we know that `method1()` or `method2()` cannot be accessed by multiple threads at the same time. But, while `method1()` is being accessed by a thread, can `method2()` be accessed by another thread?

Answer (score 3):

I think that secion 4.3.14 of the ejb 3.1 spec gives the answer.

> 4.3.14 Serializing Session Bean Methods
>   The following requirements apply to Stateless and Stateful session beans. 
>   See Section 4.8.5 for Singleton session bean concurrency requirements.
>
> The container serializes calls to each stateful and stateless session bean instance. 
>   Most containers will support many instances of a session bean executing concurrently;
>   however, each instance sees only a serialized sequence of method calls. 
>   Therefore, a stateful or stateless session bean does not have to be coded as reentrant.
>
> The container must serialize all the container-invoked callbacks 
>   (that is, the business method interceptor methods, lifecycle callback interceptor methods,
>   timeout callback methods, beforeCompletion, and so on), and it must serialize these callbacks
>   with the client-invoked business method calls.
>
> ....

As far as I understand the EJB spec you should use Singletons if you want a fine-grained control over concurrency (bean managed, container managed).

Answer (score 1):

Let's modify your example a bit

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean1 {
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    pulic void method1() {
        // method implementation
        //   As a side-effect, something is written into a database
        //   using an XA data source,
        //   and a message is sent using XA JMS
        //   (both under control of an XA transaction)
    }

    pulic int method2(int i) {
        return i * i;
    } 
}
```

For example, the **session context** is used to get the `UserTransaction` and `getCallerPrincipal`. They are not necessarily always the same (when two clients all the EJB). As for the `UserTransaction`: This one is bound to the *current thread* (see [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/UserTransaction.html)).

As the session context is stored in a field (and not passed an argument to each individual method), the same EJB instance cannot be accessed by two different clients.

Therefore the **specification** requires the container to **serialize calls** to the same instance.

If you look at `method2`, a purely functional implementation without any side-effect, there is no need for EJBs.